# How can a pure function do IO?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I recently learned about the [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t%3aMonadRandom) library.  It gives you a function called `getRandomR` and its type signature is:

```
getRandomR :: (MonadRandom m, Random a) => (a, a) -> m a
```

Apparently, you can write a function that uses `getRandomR` who type signature doesn't contain anything about `IO`.

```
computeSomething :: MonadRandom m => Int -> m Int
computeSomething a = getRandomR (0, a)
```

Depending on the caller, the `m` instance will be filled out.  If it's run from an `IO` context, the function will be impure.

So, the question: how can a function that doesn't claim to do `IO` actually do `IO`?  How can one tell if this `computeSomething` function will be pure or impure?

Comment: It's a `class` not a implementation. You can instance some pure "random" generator (eg. fixed seed, by arg, ...). The final `m` monad will decide the final purity.

Comment: Actually, the type of getRandomR is (MonadRandom m, Random a) => (a,a) -> m a.

Comment: @HonzaPokorny I've added some edits to my answer that might be better for your specific question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function `getRandomR` is not doing `IO`.  It is not required to do `IO` to generate random numbers *once you have a seed*.  The `Rand` Monad in `MonadRandom` is initialized with a seed, that can either be one that you provide for testing purposes or one pulled from IO using `evalRandIO`.  The `Rand` Monad can do this without performing `IO` actions by leveraging the pure functions exposed in `System.Random` from the `random` package, such as `random` and `randomR`.  Each of these functions takes a generator `g` and returns a new generator and a random value of the desired type.  Internally, the `Rand` Monad is really just the `State` Monad, and its state is the generator `g`.

However, it is important to note that the `IO` Monad is an instance of `MonadRandom`, where instead of using the pure state functions, it uses the normal `IO` functions like `randomIO`.  You can use `IO` and `Rand` interchangeably, but the latter will be a bit more efficient (doesn't have to perform a system call each time) and you can seed it with a known value for testing purposes to get repeatable results.

So to answer your question

> How can one tell if this `computeSomething` function will be pure or impure?

For this definition of `computeSomething`, it is neither pure or impure until the instance for `MonadRandom` is resolved.  If we take "pure" to be "not IO" and "impure" to be "IO" ([which is not entirely accurate, but a close approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)), then `computeSomething` can be pure in some instances and impure in others, just as the function `liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r` can be used on the `IO` Monad or on the `Maybe` or `[]` Monads.  In other words:

```
liftM2 (+) (Just 1) (Just 2)
```

Will always return `Just 3`, so it can be considered *pure*, while

```
liftM2 (++) getLine getLine
```

Will not always return the same thing.  While each predefined instance for `MonadRandom` would be considered impure (`RandT` and `Rand` have internal state, so they're technically impure), you could provide your own data type with an instance of `MonadRandom` for which it always returns the same value when `getRandom` or the other `MonadRandom` functions are called.  For this reason, I would say that `MonadRandom` is not inherently pure or impure.

---

Maybe some code will help explain it (simplified, I'm skipping the `RandT` transformer):

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified System.Random as R

class MonadRandom m where
    getRandom   :: Random a => m a
    getRandoms  :: Random a => m [a]
    getRandomR  :: Random a => (a, a) -> m a
    getRandomRs :: Random a => (a, a) -> m [a]

-- Not the real definition, the MonadRandom library defines a RandT
-- Monad transformer where Rand g a = RandT g Identity a, with
-- newtype RandT g m a = RandT (StateT g m a), but I'm trying to
-- keep things simple for this example.
newtype Rand g a = Rand { unRand :: State g a }

instance Monad (Rand g) where
    -- Implementation isn't relevant here

instance RandomGen g => MonadRandom (Rand g) where
    getRandom = state R.random
    getRandoms = sequence $ repeat getRandom
    getRandomR range = state (R.randomR range)
    getRandomRs range = sequence $ repeat $ getRandomR range

instance MonadRandom IO where
    getRandom = R.randomIO
    getRandoms = sequence $ repeat getRandom
    getRandomR range = R.randomRIO range
    getRandomRs range = sequence $ repeat $ getRandomR range
```

So when we have a function

```
computeSomething  :: MonadRandom m => Int -> m Int
computeSomething high = getRandomR (0, high)
```

Then we can use it as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    i <- computeSomething 10
    putStrLn $ "A random number between 0 and 10: " ++ show i
```

Or

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- evalRandIO uses getStdGen and passes the generator in for you
    i <- evalRandIO $ computeSomething 10
    putStrLn $ "A random number between 0 and 10: " ++ show i
```

Or if you wanted to use a known generator to test with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myGen = R.mkStdGen 12345
        i = evalRand (computeSomething 10) myGen
    putStrLn $ "A random number between 0 and 10: " ++ show i
```

In the last case, it will print the same number every time, making a "random" process deterministic and pure.  This gives you the ability to re-run experiments that generate random numbers by providing it an explicit seed, or you can pass in the system's random generator once, or you can use straight `IO` to get a new random generator with each call.  All of this is possible without having to change a line of code other than how it's called in `main`, the definition of `computeSomething` doesn't change between those 3 uses.